# Is there any solution for tricking vue's lifecycle hook order of execution?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Destroyed hook is called later than i need.

I tried to use beforeDestroy instead of destroy, mounted hook instead of created. The destroy hook of previous components is always called after the created hook of the components that replaces it.

App.vue

```
  <div id="app">
    <component :is="currentComponent"></component>
    <button @click="toggleComponent">Toggle component</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import A from './components/A.vue';
import B from './components/B.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    A,
    B
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      currentComponent: 'A'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComponent() {
      this.currentComponent = this.currentComponent === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    created: function() {
        shortcut.add('Enter', () => {
            console.log('Enter pressed from A');
        })
    },
    destroyed: function() {
        shortcut.remove('Enter');
    }
}
</script>
```

B.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    created: function() {
        shortcut.add('Enter', () => {
            console.log('Enter pressed from B');
        })
    },
    destroyed: function() {
        shortcut.remove('Enter');
    }
}
</script>
```

Result:

```
// Click Enter
Enter pressed from A
// now click on toggle component button
// Click Enter again
Enter pressed from A
```

Expected after the second enter to show me Enter pressed from B.

Please don't show me diagrams with vue's lifecycle, i'm already aware of that, I just need the workaround for this specific case.
Dumb answers like use setTimeout are not accepted.

EDIT: Made some changes to code and description

Comment: The question is not constructive. There's a big chance that it can only get 'dumb' answers. You likely have XY problem that needs to be solved in another way. Consider explaining your case, so the appropriate workaround could be suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `vue-router` you can use router guards in the component (as well as in the router file) where you have `beforeRouteLeave` obviously only works where there is a change in route, see here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards